# Tensor product, direct product, and direct sum?

Tags: tensor-products, direct-sum, direct-product

My question is whehter or not I'm using the direct sum $\oplus$ and direct product $\otimes$ symbols correctly, or if I need a tensor product.  I have no formal training with these symbols and if I am wrong below, I hope you will correct me.

The Cartesian plane is $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$ where $\oplus$ is the direct sum.  For comlex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, it follows that
$$ \mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}\oplus i\mathbb{R}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{i}\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{j}\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{k}\mathbb{R}~~.$$

I want to take a product of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ such that
$$ \mathbb{C}\star\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{i}\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{j}\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbf{k}\mathbb{R}\oplus i\mathbb{R}~~,$$

where $\star$ is the mystery operation I'm asking about.  If $\star$ is the operation I'm looking for, then a number in $\mathbb{C}\star\mathbb{H}$ is a 5-tuple:
$$x\in\mathbb{C}\star\mathbb{H}\qquad\implies\qquad x=\big( x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \big).$$

Please tell me what I'm looking for or use a well defined counter example to explain why my question is ill-defined.  Thanks!

Comment: $\otimes$ is not the symbol for direct product; it’s the symbol for  tensor product. Typically, we use $\times$ for the direct product, which is the same as the direct sum $\oplus$.

Comment: If your operation only ever takes $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ as its arguments, then you've *already defined the operation*. If you want your operation to apply more generally, you'll need to provide more examples and information about how you want this operation to work, why you want it, what properties you want it to have, etc. Indeed, thinking in terms of dimensions, what arithmetic operation would $2\star 4=5$ correspond to?

Comment: You should also specify what kind of objects you're thinking of these operations as involving. If they're just vanilla vector spaces, then this is clearly nonsense because your operation just identified the $\Bbb R$s of $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ together, which it shouldn't "know" how to do since vector spaces alone have no distinguished subspaces. If you're thinking of $\Bbb R$-algebras, then you should specify what the multiplication operation is on your 5D algebra $\Bbb C\star\Bbb H$.

Comment: If you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an additive group or field, then the standard notation uses the direct product: $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. If instead you consider it as a module over $\mathbb{R}$, then instead we use the direct sum $\oplus$.